# How to run a command in python with all the privilege

Tags: python, django, cron

Currently i am working on a project and i am using django-kronos for scheduling so, when user schedule a task i am running a script and end of the script i need to run

> python manage.py installtasks

this is help to insert the tasks in crontab.

script is working fine when i execute in terminal but when i integrate it with my django app, it's throwing an error

> IOError: Read crontab nobody: You (nobody) are not allowed to use this program (/usr/bin/crontab)

I really curious to know about which cause this problem?

or did i miss anything?

Comment: The error message is quite explicit: the script is ran by the user *nobody* which do not have permission to use the crontab command. You have to make the script ran by a user which have proper permissions. But since I do not know django-kronos, I am not able to tell you how to do this.

Comment: `chmod` or `chown` the script you want to run.

Comment: yeah i done the chmod and chown things.. even i gave all the permissions(755) to the script still throwing same error. But it's running perfectly when i manually run the script.. I dont know where it's got mess :(

Comment: @user458766 Did you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Setting [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) flag on the script (`chmod u+s`) will make the script run as the script file's owner UID if it's run as a separate process. You then need to watch who is allowed to execute it and/or do some authentication or check of the running user as with anyone else executing it, it'll be the same.

This is pretty much a workaround and is not advisable if some better facility is available in the app.

[From what I can see](https://github.com/jgorset/django-kronos#readme), `django-kronos` logic is supposed to be run from `manage.py` rather than web code proper.